# exporting pdf from QtextEdit pyside2 .the print button works but the pdf its not saved in my computer it is blank

Tags: python, pyside2, qprinter

```
import sys
import platform
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QPropertyAnimation, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize,QTime, QUrl, QEvent)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter, QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import QFileInfo
from PySide2.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter

from ui_interface import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.start_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.textEdit.setText("Hello World"))
        self.ui.printbutton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.SavetoPDF())
        self.show()

    def SavetoPDF(self):
        filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save to PDF', None, 'PDF files(.pdf);; All Files')
        if filename != "":
            if QFileInfo(filename).suffix() == "": filename += '.pdf'
            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
            printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
            print(self.ui.textEdit.document())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)`
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share the ui_interface file

Comment: i worked on it already. if you still want it i can share it with you bro

Comment: It is not that I want it, but it is that you must provide it since your post could be closed if you do not provide it. Please read [ask], review the [tour] and provide a [mre]